# Prove that a rotation and a translation never commute

Tags: geometry

How to prove that a rotation and a translation never commute, unless one of them is the
identity map i

Comment: Are you allowed to use matrices?

Comment: no, if I can use matrices, it's easy..it's a geometry problem

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Any non-identity rotation always fixes a unique point. Which points (if any) are fixed by $RT$ and $TR$?

Comment: center point? is it?

Comment: @user67584: $R$ fixes the "center point" of $R$, yes. It turns out $RT$ and $TR$ also have center points, but they will not be the same as the center point of $R$.

Answer (score 0):

This holds only in the plane, not in 3-space. Do you see why?

**Finding an argument:** In the complex plane, a rotation is multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$ and translation is addition of a constant. So rotation followed by translation is $f(x)=e^{i\theta}x+c$ while translation followed by rotation is $g(x)=e^{i\theta}(x+c)=e^{i\theta}x+e^{i\theta}c$. These will be different for any $\theta\ne 2\pi k$ and $c\ne 0$.

**Turning the argument into one that doesn't use complex numbers:** Thus we can choose a convenient value for $x$, like, say, $0$, and construct a purely geometric argument based on that (erasing the coordinate system, we see that the point chosen as the axis of rotation will always end up doing something different, and this is really easy to prove).

Comment: Edited to fix massively stupid error.